# Interfaces in Java, Syntax, <E>

Tags: java, interface, deque

I was asked to create my own deque interface in java, and create an array based implementation. I have a few questions why i can do this certain ways, or at least why I don't get a compiler error for either way...

Im am interested in the difference between setting up my Pile class Like i have done originally...

`public class Pile implements Deque {`

while having my declaration like this...

`Pile p = new Pile(6);`

vs.....

`public class Pile<E> implements Deque {`

and

`Pile<Thing> p = new Pile<>(6);`

??? Also if anyone see how i might have screwed up the assignment please feel free to advise haha...

Here is the code for my original code for reference....

Main Method==>

```
    public class Tester {

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thing a = new Thing();
    Thing b = new Thing();
    Thing c = new Thing();
    Thing d = new Thing();
    Thing e = new Thing();
    Thing f = new Thing();
    Thing g = new Thing();
    Thing h = new Thing();
    Thing i = new Thing();
    Thing j = new Thing();
    Thing k = new Thing();
    Thing l = new Thing();
    Thing m = new Thing();
    Thing n = new Thing();
    Thing o = new Thing();

    System.out.println("Populating Pile.....");
    Pile p = new Pile(6);
    p.addLast(a);
    p.addLast(b);
    p.addLast(c);

    System.out.println("Current status...");
    System.out.println(p.toString());
    System.out.println("Tests....");

    //--- Test... peak*()
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("peakFront() = 1 : " + p.peakFirst().toString());
    System.out.println("peakBack() = 3 : " + p.peakLast().toString());
    System.out.println("\nCurrent status...");
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    //--- Test... addLast()
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Adding Element 4 to back....");
    p.addLast(d);
    System.out.println("peakBack() = 4 : " + p.peakLast().toString());
    System.out.println("\nCurrent status...");
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    //--- Test... removeLast()
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Removing Element 4 from back....");
    System.out.println("removeBack() = 4 : " + p.removeLast().toString());
    System.out.println("peakBack() = 3 : " + p.peakLast().toString());
    System.out.println("\nCurrent status...");
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    //--- Test... addFirst();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Adding Element 4 to the front...");
    p.addFirst(d);
    System.out.println("peakFront() = 4 : " + p.peakFirst().toString());
    System.out.println("\nCurrent status...");
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    //--- Test... removeFirst()
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Removing Element 4 from the front");
    System.out.println("removeFront() = 4 : " + p.removeFirst().toString());
    System.out.println("peakFront() = 1 : " + p.peakFirst().toString());
    System.out.println("\nCurrent status...");
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    //--- Test... Tests if Size will grow dynamically at runtime...
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Current initial pile size set to " + p.getSpaceA());
    System.out.println("Overloading Pile...");
    p.addLast(d);
    p.addLast(e);
    p.addLast(f);
    p.addLast(g);
    p.addLast(h);
    p.addLast(i);
    p.addLast(j);
    p.addLast(m);
    p.addLast(n);
    p.addLast(o);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent status...");
    System.out.println(p.toStringWithNulls());
    System.out.println("expect 24 | recieve: " + p.getSpaceA());

    //--- Test... Tests if Size will shrink dynamically at runtime...
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Removing elements from pile....");
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        p.removeLast();
    }
    System.out.println("expect 12 | recieve: " + p.getSpaceA());
    System.out.println("\nCurrent status...");
    System.out.println(p.toStringWithNulls());

}

}
```

My Thing Class ==> objects Im manipulating...

```
    public class Thing {
private static int total;
private final int ID;

public Thing(){
    total++;
    ID = total;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Thing Number: " + ID;
}   
}
```

==> My deque Interface...

```
    public interface Deque<E> {

// As far as choosing the names of these operations I just googles, 
// and found what somebody on the internet claimed as common names
// I tried to put the actual java term in the comments beseide each
// Inserts element at the end
public void addLast(E target);

// Removes Element ar the end
public E removeLast();

// Returns back element with out removing it
public E peakLast();


// Insert Element at the front
public void addFirst(E target);

// Remove first element
public E removeFirst();

// Returns front element with out removing it
public E peakFirst();

// Returns the sixe of the Deque
public int size();

// Return true if empty. false if contains any elements
public boolean isEmpty();
}
```

Pile class ==> My array implementation...

```
    public class Pile implements Deque {

private int size;
Thing pile[];

public Pile(int _intitalSize) {
    size = -1;
    pile = new Thing[_intitalSize];

}

//adds a element to the last slot of the deque
@Override
public void addLast(Object target) {

    size++;
    if (checkIfTooSmall()) {
        pile = increaseSpace();
    }
    pile[size] = (Thing) target;

}

//removes from deque and reurns the last item in the deque
@Override
public Object removeLast() {
    Thing t = (Thing) pile[size];
    size--;
    if (checkIfTooBig()) {
        pile = decreaseSpace();
    }
    return t;
}

//Returns last object without removing the object from the deque
@Override
public Object peakLast() {
    return pile[size];
}

//adds a new object to the array in the first slot, while shifting data down
@Override
public void addFirst(Object target) {
    size++;
    if (checkIfTooSmall()) {
        pile = increaseSpace();
    }

    Thing[] tempPile = new Thing[pile.length + 1];
    tempPile[0] = (Thing) target;

    for (int i = 1; i < tempPile.length; i++) {
        tempPile[i] = pile[i - 1];
    }
    pile = tempPile;

}

//removes and returns first object
@Override
public Object removeFirst() {
    Thing t = (Thing) pile[0];
    Thing[] tempPile = new Thing[pile.length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < tempPile.length; i++) {
        tempPile[i] = pile[i + 1];
    }
    pile = tempPile;
    size--;
    if (checkIfTooBig()) {
        pile = decreaseSpace();
    }
    return t;
}

//returns first object without removing it from array
@Override
public Object peakFirst() {
    return pile[0];
}

//returns size index of array
@Override
public int size() {
    return size;
}

//checks if array is empty
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == -1;
}

//Check to determine if array is full
public boolean checkIfTooSmall() {
    if (size == pile.length) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//doubles array size by copying data into a new larger array
public Thing[] increaseSpace() {

    Thing[] tempPile = new Thing[pile.length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < pile.length; i++) {
        tempPile[i] = pile[i];
    }

    return tempPile;
}

//check if size index is small enough to half array size
public boolean checkIfTooBig() {
    if ((pile.length / 2) > size) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//halves array size by copying data into a new smaller array
public Thing[] decreaseSpace() {

    Thing[] tempPile = new Thing[pile.length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < tempPile.length; i++) {
        tempPile[i] = pile[i];
    }

    return tempPile;
}

//returns size of actual array
public int getSpaceA() {
    return pile.length;
}

//Shows space available in null form
public String toStringWithNulls(){
    String r = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < pile.length; i++){
        r = r + String.format(pile[i] + " |\n");
    }
    return r;
}

//shows only space populated with objects
@Override
public String toString(){
    String r = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <=  size(); i++){
        r = r + String.format(pile[i] + " |\n");
    }
    return r;
}
}
```

Comment: Also... If I really do deserve a down vote it would be nice to know why.....

Comment: To start with, you need `class Pile<E> implements Deque<E>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pile.java is coupled with Thing.java. In case '< E >' was used then Pile could have been able to contain entities other than Thing.java objects based upon the type during instantiating Pile.java. Client code would  have been forced to add only the type of objects as per the 'type' mentioned during instantiating Pile object.

Here In your code if client code tries to add anythig other than Thing.java objects there is no one stopping doing so. In case objects of any other type is added then the code would blow up with ClassCastException.